# How to create multiple flows for different nodes with different jars in Corda?

Tags: corda

How to create multiple flows for different nodes with different jar files in Corda platform?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle Example [here](https://github.com/corda/samples) is a good example. You need to do several things:

1. Split the source files for the different JAR files into separate modules. In the example linked above, there is a separate module for `base`, `service` and `client`. Make sure you include the modules in the [`settings.gradle` file](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/oracle-example/settings.gradle)
2. Include the modules as dependencies in your [main `build.gradle` file](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/oracle-example/build.gradle#L79)
3. How you install these CorDapps then depends on how you are creating your nodes:

   - If you are using `deployNodes` to create your nodes, [selectively add the modules as CorDapps on your nodes](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/oracle-example/build.gradle#L113)
   - If you are creating the nodes manually:

     - Run the `gradlew jar` task from the root of your project to create the individual CorDapps in the `build/libs` folder
     - Copy these CorDapps to the `cordapps` folder of the nodes you want them to be installed on
     - Restart the nodes